# Elevation/LiDAR/DTM Data with resolution less than 5m for Cheshire UK

Tags: data-request, geospatial, open-source

I'm trying to find some elevation data - either LiDAR, elevation or DTM - for the UK, specifically in Cheshire. I am a University student, so have access to gov data and other databases. I currently have the OS Terrain 5 which has a resolution of 5m. Ideally I need 1-2m or less. However, I can't find this.

Any ideas of whether this data is out there?

UPDATE:
I have tried the government portal, however, my site is currently part of the country that has yet to be mapped. This is the government coverage for the area I am looking for (Brown layer). The green polygon is the area I need data for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://data.gov.uk/dataset/f0db0249-f17b-4036-9e65-309148c97ce4/national-lidar-programme

National lidar survey should fit the bill for you

Comment: Government data has missing gaps for my area. See update.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this answer by saying that I'm more familiar with how things are mapped in Wales than in England.

However, DEFRA has a [lidar composite dataset](https://environment.data.gov.uk/dataset/13787b9a-26a4-4775-8523-806d13af58fc) available at 1m resolution for 2022. It appears to have complete coverage in Cheshire. You can see this by loading a preview of the DTM in QGIS using the Web Mapping Service (WMS):

- https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/lidar-composite-digital-terrain-model-dtm-1m-2022/wms

[image]

If the data is not available at 1m resolution, you might try lowering the resolution:

- [LIDAR Composite DTM 2022 – 2m](https://www.data.gov.uk/dataset/e529ca2f-b4ce-403e-8cef-ab821061c4f3/lidar-composite-dtm-2022-2m)
- [LIDAR Composite DTM 2022 – 10m](https://www.data.gov.uk/dataset/7f31af0f-bc98-4761-b4b4-147bfb986648/lidar-composite-dtm-2022-10m)